# time & space complexity analysis for this recursive python function which return all subset of a set

Tags: python, recursion, big-o, time-complexity, subset

So I write this fn, but I don't know how to analyze it's time and space complexity. Really have no clue.

Can you help me by point out a direction or how would you approach this analysis?

```
def subset(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return [a, []] # the key is you should return yourself and []
    else:
        return subset(a[:-1]) + [ s + [a[-1]] for s in subset(a[:-1])]

print(subset([1,2,3]))

terminal: [[1], [], [1, 2], [2], [1, 3], [3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: For the one who gave me down vote, give me a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module that measure execution time of small code snippets.

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""
def subset(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return [a, []] # the key is you should return yourself and []
    else:
        return subset(a[:-1]) + [ s + [a[-1]] for s in subset(a[:-1])]
"""

print ' complexity : ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
```

result :

```
complexity:  0.00803089141846
```

And for find the memory usage you can use [`memory-profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

Comment: Thanks. I happen to be using ipython and  know how to time the fn call. Also thanks for the mem profiler, never used it. Looks interesting. However, I do want to understand the asymptotic complexity of this function, and how to derive it.